# grep and cut with one more spaces

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a method in bash script that does something like this

```
status=$(docker service ls|grep $1|cut -f7 -d' '| grep -w "1/1")
```

The value `$1=abc_mongodb1` or `$1=abc_mongodb2` and so on. It tells me if string `1/1` exists it means my service is up. The problem happens when the output of `docker service ls` has different number of spaces because the names of services vary in length. How do I tell the delimiter in the cut part of the pipe to use one or more spaces. The following types of outputs are possible

```
Output of type1
`ID            NAME          MODE        REPLICAS  IMAGE
fw2qdrh38oeq  abc_mongodb2  replicated  1/1       mongo:3.4
l9mvn0wvqaxy  abc_mongodb1  replicated  1/1       mongo:3.4
pfjlpa29yb59  abc_mongodb3  replicated  1/1       mongo:3.4`
```

My cut command works fine in the above. It fails in the below case

```
Output of type 2(failure case)
ID            NAME                 MODE        REPLICAS  IMAGE
45uhn1au50ue  abc_deltaservice     replicated  1/1       abc-deltaservice:latest
cubbmpw657ib  abc_mongodb1         replicated  1/1       mongo:3.4
gil4c53jrvyc  abc_mongodb2         replicated  1/1       mongo:3.4
hy9ooec4rapd  abc_executionengine  replicated  1/1       abc-executionengine:latest
vocsigy76ab0  msc_mongodb3         replicated  1/1       mongo:3.4
ze4jg0f2y0jt  abc_kongdb           replicated  1/1       postgres:9.4
```

Comment: Use `awk` instead of `cut`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delete any additional spaces from input with `sed` before sending it as input to `cut` command

```
sed 's/ \+/\ /g'
```

this command will replace any sequence of more than one space to a single space

so your command will look something like:

```
status=$(docker service ls|grep $1|sed 's/ \+/\ /g'|cut -f7 -d' '| grep -w "1/1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` which handles repeated spaces gracefully:

```
status=$(docker service ls | awk -v service=$1 '$2 == service { print $4 }' | grep -w "1/1")
```

You can eliminate `grep` by adding that check to `awk`:

```
status=$(docker service ls | awk -v service=$1 '$2 == service && $4 == "1/1" { print $4 }')
```

or, to make it a little more clear:

```
status=$(docker service ls | awk -v service=$1 -v state="1/1" '$2 == service && $4 == state { print $4 }')
```

Comment: thanks, I just used tr as follows, is using tr a bad idea?
`docker service ls|grep "msc_mongodb1"|tr -s ' '|cut -f4 -d ' '|grep -w "1/1"`

Comment: `tr` or `sed` can be used for trimming spaces, but `awk` is the best tool for field extraction and filtering.